# How do I access a specific pointer, within an array of structures?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, structure

I have a structure with two pointers that I am storing inside of an array of the same type. I am unsure of how to access the pointers in each specific index of the array.

```
class List 
{
public:
 List();

private:
 struct L_Node
  {
    L_Node *next;
    L_Node *prev;
    int     iValue;  // not actually doing anything in this example
  }

 L_Node head[4];
 L_Node tail[4];
}
```

In the constructor, I am wanting head[0] next to be pointing to tail[0] next, head[1] next to tail[1] next and so on, with *prev to be pointing from tail to head to form a doubly linked list. For head, prev = NULL, and in tail next=NULL. In between the head and tail arrays, I am trying to have some dynamic instances of L_Node.

As of now, in my constructor, I have

```
head->next = new L_Node;
head->prev = NULL;

tail->next = NULL;
tail->prev = new L_Node;

head->next->next = tail;
tail->prev->prev = head;
```

It compiles, however I am unsure of how it is behaving. Is head[0] pointing through the dynamic struct to tail[0] and so on?

Thanks in advance for any help or tips.

EDIT:

would a typedef for a pointer such as

```
typedef L_Node *L_Ptr;
```

be of help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, this is what you need in the constructor of `List`:

```
List::List()
{
   for (int i = 0; i != 4; ++i )
   {
      head[i].next = tail[i];
      tail[i].prev = head[i];
   }
}
```

I would add a constructor in `L_Node` to have sane initial values for its member data.

```
L_Node() : next(NULL), prev(NULL), iValue(0) {}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was going crazy with this, I kept on using the arrow (->) for whatever reason haha

Comment: Glad I could be of help.